# Hi I have been studying English for few months by my own as I can't attend courses, I have this example I didn't understand

Tags: british-english

why they wrote in oxford work book next question as  correct answer:

can you tell me where the waiting rooms are?

and the next question as wrong:
can you tell me where are the waiting rooms?

Comment: Both answers are wrong. The correct construction is: **Can you (please) tell me where the waiting room IS.** Alternatively **...where the waiting rooms are.**

Comment: Thanks, why you wrote it,can you please tell me where the wating rooms are.  I mean why you put the are at the end not after "where"

Comment: You can ask **Can you please tell me where are the waiting rooms?** But, although people will understand you perfectly well, this is not the way we we speak. See Colin Fine's answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In direct questions, we invert the subject and the verb or auxiliary:

> Where are the waiting rooms?

In indirect (embedded) questions, we don't:

> Can you tell me where the waiting rooms are.